# Find a substring with Javascript or Regex in GTM variable

Tags: javascript, include, substring, google-tag-manager

I need to find a substring e.g. "collapsible" in a string from a GTM variable that looks like this:

"HTMLHeadingElement: html > body.pageHomeNO.pageSitemapNO.jsOK.touchO" +
"K > main > section.cSubJobs.collapsible.job-02-tun > div > h2.h1"

In the Tag Assistant the string has 2 breaks ([Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46Tub.jpg)). If I search for a string from the first line, the code & regex works but not if its a string from line 2 or 3.

Javascript:

```
function () {
  
var akkordeon="{{DLV - element}}";
var check = akkordeon.includes("collapsible");

return check;
}
```

Regex:

```
\bcollapsible\b
```

Edit: As Darrellwan pointed out it is not a string. The "Return Type" says "string" so I assumed it is one ([Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELdEd.jpg)). I need the "Click Element" as a trigger. If someone clicks on the Element "collapsible" the trigger should fire.

Comment: The screenshot you attach is a dom element. Not a string (even it looks like string). We might need to know what you are looking for. Do you need something from the dom `section.collapsible` (The section element with class has 'collapsible')?